# Changing the shape of tkinter widgets

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

So I have a simple button:

```
f1button3=Button(text="Database", command = lambda: DatabaseWidgets()).place(x=1,y=30)
```

The button is always a rectangle, but I want it to have curved edges, or possibly even change the shape. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You can sort of get a different look for some widgets with `ttk`, but it's quite fragile.

Comment: @LHez not in tkinter, only in ttk. One method is to bind to a canvas after redrawing the window and bind actions to the canvas as if it had buttons. Another is the method I've linked below after searching for redrawing a window.

__http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0383/Demo/tkinter/ttk/roundframe.py__

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem. My solution was to use an image, then bind that to a click. Here is the code I used:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

app = Tk()

def do(event):
    print("Button Clicked!")
    #...

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Button.gif"))
button = Label(app, image = img)
button.pack()

button.bind('<Button-1>', do)

app.mainloop()
```

The `<Button-1>` binds the image to a right click. The `"Button.gif"` is the picture I used.

Here is the output picture:

[image: The output]