# Changing shapes of tkinter scale widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, scale

I want to change the shape of tkinter scale widgets. Basically I want to change both the slider and trough to a different shape. Does anyone know how to do this? I looked online and did not find any results for my query. As im new to tkinter, please try to keep it simple. I found some results on changing the shape of the button widget ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328547/changing-the-shape-of-tkinter-widgets)) but this did not seem to help me much. I want my scales to look something like the scales shown on the top of this image:

[image: example of desired look]

The scales do not have to look exactly the same as that in the pic above. Any advice on how to make my scale look better will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant part of my code :

```
scale1 = ttk.Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,variable=s_var1)
scale2 = ttk.Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,variable=s_var2)
scale3 = ttk.Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,variable=s_var3)
scale4 = ttk.Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,variable=s_var4)
scale5 = ttk.Scale(root,from_=100,to=0,orient=VERTICAL,variable=s_var5)
#displaying the scale widgets on the screen
scale1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=40,pady=10)
scale2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=40,pady=10)
scale3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=40,pady=10)
scale4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=40,pady=10)
scale5.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=40,pady=10)
#disabling the scales
scale1.config(state=DISABLED)
scale2.config(state=DISABLED)
scale3.config(state=DISABLED)
scale4.config(state=DISABLED)
scale5.config(state=DISABLED)
```

I've also used tkinter.ttk module but I didn't like its widgets either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pictures, I assume that you want to display some amounts, not use scales to select values. In this case, I would rather use a `Progressbar` than a `Scale`. This will give you something similar than the top of your pictures but with simple rectangular shapes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

# configure Progressbar style to be flat and with the colors from the pictures
style.configure('my.Vertical.TProgressbar', background='#f7f4bf', troughcolor='#8a7852',
                pbarrelief='flat', troughrelief='flat')

pbar1 = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=100, value=25, orient='vertical', style='my.Vertical.TProgressbar')
pbar2 = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=100, value=74, orient='vertical', style='my.Vertical.TProgressbar')
pbar3 = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=100, value=10, orient='vertical', style='my.Vertical.TProgressbar')
pbar4 = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=100, value=45, orient='vertical', style='my.Vertical.TProgressbar')
pbar5 = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=100, value=50, orient='vertical', style='my.Vertical.TProgressbar')

pbar1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40, pady=10)
pbar2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=40, pady=10)
pbar3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=40, pady=10)
pbar4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=40, pady=10)
pbar5.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=40, pady=10)

root.configure(bg="#231303")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

You can change the value displayed by the progressbar with `pbar1.configure(value=<new_value>)`.

However, I don't know how to change the shape of the progressbar. To get a custom shape for the bar, it is possible to create a custom bar class from a Canvas and use PIL to get a transparent shape.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)


class MyBar(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, shape, value=0, maximum=100,
                 bg="#231303", trough_color='#8a7852', bar_color='#f7f4bf'):
        # open shape mask with PIL
        im_shape_alpha = Image.open(shape).convert('L')
        # create bar shape image with the choosen backgroound color
        im_shape = Image.new('RGBA', im_shape_alpha.size, bg)
        # apply shape as alpha mask to "cut out" the bar shape
        im_shape.putalpha(im_shape_alpha)
        width, height = im_shape_alpha.size
        # create the canvas
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg=trough_color, width=width, height=height, highlightthickness=0)

        self._value = value  # bar value
        self.maximum = maximum  # maximum value

        # bar width and height
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        
        # create tkinter image for the shape from the PIL Image
        self.img_trough = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_shape, master=self)
        # create bar to display the value
        self.create_rectangle(0, height, width, height * (1 - value/self.maximum), width=0, fill=bar_color, tags='pbar')
        # display shape on top
        self.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=self.img_trough)

    @property
    def value(self):
        """Return bar's value'"""
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        """Set bar's value'"""
        self._value = value
        # adjust bar height to value
        self.coords('pbar', 0, self.height, self.width, self.height*(1 - value/self.maximum))

shape = '/path/to/shape/picture'

bar1 = MyBar(root, shape)
bar2 = MyBar(root, shape)
bar3 = MyBar(root, shape)
bar4 = MyBar(root, shape)
bar5 = MyBar(root, shape=shape, value=60, bg='navy', trough_color='sky blue', bar_color='royal blue')

bar1.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=40)
bar2.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=40)
bar3.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=40)
bar4.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=40)
bar5.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=40)

bar2.value = 75
bar3.value = 50
bar4.value = 100
root.mainloop()
```

Result: [image: screenshot shaped bars]

Image used for `shape` in this example: [image: shape image]

In the above code, `shape` is a black and white picture which is used as an alpha mask. The idea is that the bar is a rectangle of `bar_color` drawn on a `Canvas` with background `trough_color`. Then on top of this bar I put an image of color `bg`, except for the shape part which is transparent and has been cut out of the background (black part of `shape` picture).

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful and solved my problem. I'm actually very new to tkinter so I didnt know about progress bars.

Comment: @Jovan You're welcome. I've added to my answer a way to get a shaped bar. It is more complicated than just using a Progressbar but I have put comments in the code to try to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the trouble. I was starting to think that I would have to stick to the boring default style of tkinter scale widgets. And yeah i understood what you did. Thanks again.